# Clarity Design sidenav can't scroll when content exceeds view

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, sidenav

So I'm currently using the sidenav, but when the nav links exceed the view I can't scroll to see the "hidden" links unless I zoom out.

I'm using Angular 5 as a frontend framework and this is how I arranged the components:

```
<nav class="sidenav">
  <students>
  </students>
</nav>
```

Inside the students component:

```
<section class="sidenav-content">
  <section class="nav-group">
    <label>Alumnos</label>

    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li *ngFor="let student of students | orderBy: 'number'">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          [class.active]="studentIdSelected == student.id"
          (click)="selectStudent(student)">
        {{ student.number }} - {{ student.name }}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="addStudent()">Agregar alumno</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything since I followed the docs and expected to get the scrolling option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the layout correctly? More info about the layout can be found here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/app-layout

Please take a look at this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-mkudjf?file=app/app.component.html

The layout markup is:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="header-2">
    Header
  </header>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
      Content Area
    </div>
    <nav class="sidenav">
       ...
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.sidenav` goes after the `.content-area`

EDIT:
Please note that the Clarity team recommends you use Vertical Nav instead of the sidenav. The documentation for vertical nav is here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/vertical-nav/basic-structure/charmander

Comment: Yeah, I just made sure that the `.sidenav` is after `.content-area` inside `.main-container`, everything is used correctly. I can try using the vertical nav but I'm not sure how that will look along with the full markup.

Comment: Did you also check the `.content-container`? Could you replicate this on a StackBlitz?

Comment: If you use vertical nav, it will go in place of the sidenav (right after the content area)